# Is there a way to prevent focus from blurring from an element when the user clicks the small space between javascript mottie virtual keyboard keys?

Tags: javascript, html, virtual-keyboard

I have a simple web application and I'm having trouble wrangling the mottie virtual keyboard in a specific situation.

My screen has a number of fields.  If the user clicks one of the text boxes (a virtual keyboard is bound to each text box), an on-focus function hides the other elements on the page and enlarges the current field/label.

The virtual keyboard works great in this state.  When I enter text then click Accept or click the area outside of the virtual keyboard's rectangle, focus blurs and the keyboard disappears and all the fields are again shown.

The problem I'm having is that when the user clicks the tiny space between the virtual keys, or any area that's not a key within the rectangle of the virtual keyboard, the keyboard stays visible (as it should) but all other elements flash onscreen behind the keyboard for the duration of the downclick.  So the downclick is causing focus to blur from the selected element, only to immediately focus again as soon as downclick is released.

I was hoping there was some parameter of the virtual keyboard that would make any non-key portion of the virtual keyboard a dead zone for clicks, but I haven't been able to find it.  Does anyone has experience with this?  Thanks!

Comment: In the onclick/mousedown handler for the keyboard, add e.stopPropagation() and that will prevent any containing or underlying siblings from receiving the click event.

Comment: Please produce the error in a fiddle or what so ever. We cannot help you with just a bunch of text, while we try to figure out what kind of code is possibly used ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return focus to the text box, then maybe try something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/egb3a1sk/7077/)):

```
$(function() {
  $('#keyboard').keyboard({
      visible: function(e, keyboard, el) {
        keyboard.$keyboard.on('mousedown', function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            keyboard.$preview.focus();
          }, 100);
        });
      }
    });
});
```

I started out by making it on 'click', but it didn't focus until after the mouse was released. I'm not sure why you're seeing everything fade out (maybe a css `:active` setting?) but this could should *almost* immediately restore focus.